# Race conditions on shared memory on uniprocessor?

Tags: c, operating-system, synchronization

I have written the following code where the parent creates a shared memory object which then calls the fork system call API, to create a child process.
As expected I am facing inconsistency problems as shared memory object will be used by both of them and race conditions arise.
What I don't understand is, when I run the process with taskset on single processor there are no race conditions?
what could be the possible reason behind this kind of behavior?

```
//init Attachmem as shared memory object having countval as a member
 int main(){
        pid_t retval;                       
        int status;                         
        retval=fork();                          
        if(retval<0){                           
            perror("Fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    printf("When Parent donot waits for child \n\n\n");
    if(retval>0){                           
        while(dummycount){                  
            Attachmem->countval++;              
            dummycount--;
        }
        printf("PARENT::In parent context value of Countval becomes %d\n",Attachmem->countval); //shared object
        printf("PARENT::In parent context value of dummycount  becomes %d \n",dummycount);  //parent specific object
    }   
    if(retval==0){                          
        dummycount=0;
        while(Attachmem->countval){             
            dummycount++;       

        }
        printf("CHILD::In child context the value of Countval  becomes %d\n",Attachmem->countval);
        printf("CHILD::In child context the value of dummycount becomes %d\n",dummycount);
        error(0);
    }


 return 0;
}
```

Output::
**When child and Parent run on different Processors**

```
CHILD::In child context the value of Countval  becomes 0
CHILD::In child context the value of dummycount becomes 16897
./a.out: : Unknown error 16897
PARENT::In parent context value of Countval becomes 479145
PARENT::In parent context value of dummycount  becomes 0
```

**When child and Parent run on the same processor using taskset**

```
PARENT::In parent context value of Countval becomes 500000
PARENT::In parent context value of dummycount  becomes 0 
When Parent donot waits for child 


CHILD::In child context the value of Countval  becomes 0
CHILD::In child context the value of dummycount becomes 500000
./a.out: : Unknown error 500000
```

I am currently running OpenSuse with linux kernel 3.16.6

Comment: I presume you're running on x86? If so, the behavior is quite understandable. The compiler will probably use register-memory forms of the `inc` or `add` instruction. It *won't* use `lock inc/add` for non-atomic data, so the instructions would *not* be atomic to a separate processor on the memory bus, but by the semantics of precise exceptions these single instructions *are* atomic to code that runs concurrently on *the same* processor. That said, this is undefined behavior and not a good idea.

Comment: @EOF thanks for the reply, yes I am on x86, considering the exception in the pipe lining the behavior of program must change during overloading conditions, but the output seems to be very consistent.

Comment: @EOF Could you shed some more light please? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I really can't. The code you've posted is incomplete, and the parts that are there are *probably* incorrect as well. The fundamental problem is that undefined behavior cannot be reasoned with. It is permitted to exhibit *any* behavior, including running without showing signs of the race condition.